# Error when using Python to create hyperlink within a worksheet in Excel

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink

I am trying add hyperlinking functionality in my Excel documents by being able to click on a cell and it will take me to another part of the Excel document. I have code below that should take me to cell A21 when I click on A1. The code executes fine, but when I click on the link, a window pops up saying "Cannot open the specified file." Is there a problem with the way I'm referencing the cell? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')

def main():
    CreateLink()

def CreateLink():
    cell_location = excel.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)
    cell_destination = excel.Worksheets(1).Cells(21,1)
    cell_text = "Cell A21"
    excel.Worksheets(1).Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor=cell_location, Address=cell_destination, TextToDisplay=cell_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def CreateLink():
    excel.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = '=HYPERLINK(A21,"Cell A21")'
```

Comment: Yes same message. Could there be a problem with the file path? Is it working on your machine?

Comment: But if I keep the destination cell empty, I don't see the message. When I add text to the destination cell, the message comes. Of course I would prefer having text.

Comment: What do you expect to get when you click on a link?

Comment: Excel should navigate to the cell. i.e. Make it the active cell, and move down or up so the cell is visible if needed.

Comment: Ok, try this: `excel.Worksheets(1).Cells(20,1).Value = '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A21","Cell A21")'`

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely put me in the right direction, I can work with that! :)

Comment: Sorry, quick follow up question: Is there a way to specify the cell reference as (row,column) format i.e.: (58,1) instead of A58?

Comment: Can a variable name be used? i.e.: cell_text = "Cell A58"

excel.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = '=HYPERLINK("#Sheet1!A58",cell_text)'

Surely, this can't only work manually? What if I want to do this for multiple cells?

Answer (score 1):

Use `xlsxwriter` module to do it as simple as it is, [have a look at the documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html)

```
# Link to a cell on the current worksheet.
worksheet.write_url('A1',  'internal:Sheet2!A1')

# Link to a cell on another worksheet.
worksheet.write_url('A2',  'internal:Sheet2!A1:B2')

# Worksheet names with spaces should be single quoted like in Excel.
worksheet.write_url('A3',  "internal:'Sales Data'!A1")

# Link to another Excel workbook.
worksheet.write_url('A4', r'external:c:\temp\foo.xlsx')

# Link to a worksheet cell in another workbook.
worksheet.write_url('A5', r'external:c:\foo.xlsx#Sheet2!A1')

# Link to a worksheet in another workbook with a relative link.
worksheet.write_url('A7', r'external:..\foo.xlsx#Sheet2!A1')

# Link to a worksheet in another workbook with a network link.
worksheet.write_url('A8', r'external:\\NET\share\foo.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Make sure you include single quotes when you reference another sheet in a Workbook hyperlink.

# example code to link the same cell on two different worksheet

import win32com.client as win32com

output_filename = 'MyExcelWorkbook.xlsx'
excel = win32com.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb    = excel.Workbooks.Open(output_filename)

worksheet1name = wb.Worksheets(1).Name
worksheet2name = wb.Worksheets(2).Name
ws_out         = wb.Worksheets.(worksheet1name)

for rowIndex in range(numRows):
    rangeString = 'A' + str(rowIndex)
    cell_destination = '\'' + sheet2name + '\'' + '!' + 'A' + str(rowIndex)
    ws_out.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor=ws_out.Range(rangeString), Address='', SubAddress=cell_destination)
```

Comment: Hi James, consider adding some explanation of your solution. Its not immediately clear how this solves the Shankar's problem.

Comment: The answer could have been redacted a little bit better, but this is the one that worked for me! Thanks!